# BlackBerry Smartphone 9300 ,error message “ Error starting "appName":Error loading module’appName”

Tags: blackberry, module, runtime-error, loading

i submitted my application to blackberry app world and they send me --->After I tested on the BlackBerry Smartphone 9300 there is appear error message “ Error starting guess$20Me$27s_320x240:Error loading module’guess$20Me”

"guessMe" is my application name....

Comment: did you test the app on your simulator ?.

Comment: More importantly, did you actually test your app on a 9300 Simulator!

Comment: @Signare yes i tested my application on model 9300 and it was running fine